# Python Unittest importting classes with defined variables when it shouldn't

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

First Testing file I have. The test passes fine

```
from unittest import TestCase
from post import Post
from blog import Blog


    
class TestBlogPost(TestCase):
    def test_json(self):
        b = Blog('Test', 'Test Author')
        b.CreatePost('Test Post', 'Test Content')
```

The next test fails because Blog already has a post in it. I don't understand why because they're in different files and I'm pretty sure blog = Blog() creates a new instance of Blog

```
from unittest import TestCase
from blog import Blog
from post import Post


class BlogTest(TestCase):

    def test_Constructor(self):

        blog = Blog('apple blog', 'andrew yung')
        self.assertEqual('apple blog', blog.title)
        self.assertEqual('andrew yung', blog.author)
        self.assertListEqual([], blog.posts)
```

Souce code for Post

```
class Post:

    __slots__ = ['title', 'content']

    def __init__(self, title: str, content: str) -> 'Post':
        """
        A post in the blog system

        Attributes:
            title: str: The Title of the post
            content: str: The Content in the post
        """
        self.title = title
        self.content = content

    def __eq__(self, other: 'Post') -> bool:
        """
        test if two posts are equal toz
        """
        return (self.title == other.title and self.content == other.content)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.title} - post title'
    
    def __str(self) -> str:
        return self.__repr__()
        

    def json(self) -> dict:
        return {
            'title': self.title,
            'content': self.content,
        }
```

Souce code for Blog

The issue doesn't happen when I add an empty list as an argument in the test.
I don't understand why it's not using the default value for blog when I initialize without the 'posts' parameter in the test.

```
from typing import List, Optional
from post import Post


class Blog:
    """
    class that represents a blog

    """

    __slots__ = ['title', 'author', 'posts']

    def __init__(self, title: str, author: str, posts: List['Post'] = []):
        """
        Constructor for a blog

        Attributes:
            title: str: The Title of the blog
            author: str: The Author of the blog
            posts: List[Post]: The Posts the blog has
        """

        self.title: str = title
        self.author: str = author
        self.posts: List[Post] = posts


    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        
        return "{} by {} ({} post{})".format(self.title,
                                            self.author,
                                            len(self.posts),
                                            's' if len(self.posts) != 1 else '')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.__repr__()

    def __eq__(self, other: 'Blog') -> bool:
        return self.author == other.author and self.posts == other.posts and self.title == other.title
    
    def CreatePost(self, title: str, content: str, post: Optional[Post] = None) -> None:
        
        #adding a post to the list of posts
        #Ik this is a stupid way to do this because you'll still need 3 arguments if you have
        # a post you wanna add. But I don't care python doesn't have overloading like C++ 
        # and I'm not in the mood to figure out a better way
        # will come back to this tho
        self.posts.append(Post(title, content)) if post is None else self.posts.append(post)




    def json(self):
        return {
            'title': self.title,
            'author': self.author,
            'posts': [post.json() for post in self.posts],
        }
```

Finally the output for the test that failed
self.assertListEqual([], blog.posts)
AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != [Test Post - post title]

Second list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
Test Post - post title

- []

- [Test Post - post title]

and the second test
self.assertEqual(b.**repr**(), 'Test by Test Author (0 posts)')
AssertionError: 'Test by Test Author (1 post)' != 'Test by Test Author (0 posts)'

- Test by Test Author (1 post)
  ?                      ^

- Test by Test Author (0 posts)
  ?

Comment: need blog and post source code to solve this problem

Comment: Updated. I looked through the debugger for Blog and the 'posts' parameter is starting with a post already in it. I don't know why though.

Comment: I run your code it just works fine and passed all tests. Could you show the assert fail message or traceback? Btw,'posts' parameter you set it default value to [] in the method "init",so it is starting with a post already in it

Comment: I uploaded the test results. I think you found where I made a mistake but I'm still confused. When I set the default value to [] in the 'init' method for post. I did so thinking the default would be an empty list. Apparently that's not the case and I don't understand why. Thanks for help btw!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the edit I fixed the unittest code,maybe misunderstand what you want to test.If so please comment to me.

code:

```
import unittest
from post import Post
from blog import Blog

class TestBlogPost(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_json(self):
        b = Blog('Test', 'Test Author')
        b.CreatePost('Test Post', 'Test Content')
        self.assertListEqual(b.posts,[])
#the first assert error happened here, AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != [Test Post - post title]
        self.assertEqual(b.__repr__(), 'Test by Test Author (0 posts)')
#the second assert error happened here, AssertionError: 'Test by Test Author (1 post)' != 'Test by Test Author (0 posts)'

class BlogTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Constructor(self):
        blog = Blog('apple blog', 'andrew yung')
        self.assertEqual('apple blog', blog.title)
        self.assertEqual('andrew yung', blog.author)
        self.assertListEqual(blog.posts,[])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

- In the `b.CreatePost('Test Post', 'Test Content')`,you change the posts value to `[Test Post - post title]`,so it isn't equal to `[]`.
- So that posts length is 1 not 0, `__repr__` become `Test by Test Author (1 post)`